# image not showing in the templates in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

When I add song from my database everything is working fine but the image is not showing up in the templates.  How can I solve that?

This is my template:

```
 {% for audio in songs %}

 <div class="player">

    <div class="imgBx">
      <div>
        <p>{{audio.book_title}}</p>

        <p>{{audio.artist}}</p>

        <p>{{audio.author}}</p>
      </div>
        <img src="{{object.image_url}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <audio controls>

    <source src="{{audio.file.url}}" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
 </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Audio(models.Model):
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='file')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=file, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title
        def image_url():
            if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
                return self.image.url
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Audio

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    context = {'songs': Audio.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: have to set up your media_root and media_url  in the settings.py file? if don't know about them show us your urls.py file of the PROJECT

Answer (score 0):

You can make you of python [Property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/glossary/#term-property) inside of your django models like below.

```
class Audio(models.Model):
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="file")
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=file, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        """
        Returns a image url if the audio has an image.
        """
        return self.image.url if self.image else None
```

Comment: sir is not working again

Comment: What issue are you facing? Is it returning None when the audio is having an image? Try changing upload_to of image field in the model  like this `image = models.ImageField(upload_to=file, null=True, blank=False)`

Comment: come on my friend is already working fine. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistake in `<img src="{{object.image_url}}" alt="">`, which should be `<img src="{{audio.image.url}}" alt="">`

Comment: Thank you so much my friend it's now working fine. i am so proud of you